# How to change the Checkbox shape using ANTD

Tags: antd

This is for terms&condition kind of page where there is checkbox next to the term. I dont know how to change the checkbox shape and it still stuck as a blue square. Please help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would update the style by applying a classname to the Checkbox and changing the CSS.

Something like:

```html
// style.css
.ant-checkbox.foo span.ant-checkbox-inner {
  background-color: hotpink;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

// jsx
<Checkbox className="foo" />
```